# How to WordPess CRON auto run every 1 minutes in localhost

Tags: wordpress

When i load page cron running good but we want auto run every 60 seconds in localhost.
Any one help me.

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_every_three_minutes' );
function isa_add_every_three_minutes( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_three_minutes'] = array(
            'interval'  => 60,
            'display'   => __( 'Every 1 Minutes', 'textdomain' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}

// Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'isa_add_every_three_minutes' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_three_minutes', 'isa_add_every_three_minutes' );
}

// Hook into that action that'll fire every three minutes
add_action( 'isa_add_every_three_minutes', 'every_three_minutes_event_func' );
function every_three_minutes_event_func() {
    $content = "some text here";
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/wordpressrootfolder/".time()."-myText.txt","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Wordpress CronJobs work a little different then traditional CronJobs. They will only run when WordPress is loaded, if the interval time has passed. As such, on localhost, you would have to find a way for the page to be loaded regularly.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy if you have access to the server's crontab via SSH or cPanel.

You are able to set wp-cron.php to run in a normal cron task on your server and set this to run at an interval of your choosing. I personally don't let wp-cron.php run on many of my sites as once your cron tasks get bulky it can affect page load speed.

The cron task you want to run is `wget -q -O - https://example.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron >/dev/null 2>&1` where you want to replace example.com with your own domain.

For further details, I find this article quite useful https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/disable-wp-cron/

Comment: Thanks for response don’t want server side because this my custom plugin

Comment: So you want a plugin to be able to tell a server when to run a cron task? You're going to be limited to waiting on someone visiting the site then. There isn't a way of running a cron task using WP-Cron unless the site is visited. 

I've seen people trying to do this by setting up a site monitor but this is messy and you cannot guarantee it will run every x minutes.

Comment: Auto run it’s not possible?

Comment: Not if you don't want to access the server crontab. Clients cannot control scheduled tasks unless they run.